# zmq.error.ZMQError: Socket operation on non-socket: How to find alive sockets before closing?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

In my application, I'm creating 2 sockets and have a try/except for this:

```
try:
    socketA.connect("tcp://localhost:5557")
    socketB.bind("tcp://localhost:5558")
except zmq.ZMQError as e:

    if e.errno == zmq.EINVAL:
        logger.error("Endpoint supplied is invalid")
    else:
        logger.error("The ZeroMQ error with an error number {0}".format(e.errno))
        raise ZMQError(e)
    cleanUp()
```

If for some reason, one of the sockets cannot `.connect()`/`.bind()`, I want to close both sockets and terminate the context in a `cleanUp()` function, but how will I know which sockets are alive before closing them?

Does ZeroMQ provide any information about active sockets before closing them nicely?

Answer (score 4):

### Given the logic above, let us use another approach:

**Case A:** both sockets did `.connect()` + `.bind()` respectively
**Case B:**  any of sockets did fail in doing so.

```
 try:
       socketA.connect(   "tcp://localhost:5557" )
       socketA.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )
       try:
            socketB.bind(      "tcp://localhost:5558" )
            socketB.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )

       except zmq.ZMQError as e:

            if ( e.errno in ( zmq.EINVAL, 
                              zmq.EPROTONOSUPPORT,
                              zmq.ENOCOMPATPROTO,
                              zmq.EADDRINUSE,
                              zmq.EADDRNOTAVAIL,
                              )
                 ):
                 logger.error( "ZeroMQ TransportClass / Endpoint cannot be setup for [socketB]." )

            if ( e.errno in ( zmq.ENODEV,
                              zmq.ENOTSOCK,
                              )
                 ):
                 logger.error( "ZeroMQ request was made against a non-existent device or not using a valid socket [socketB]." )

            if ( e.errno in ( zmq.ETERM,
                              zmq.EMTHREAD,
                              )
                 ):
                 logger.error( "ZeroMQ Context is not in a state to handle this request for [socketB]." )


            cleanUp( aContextINSTANCE, [ socketA, socketB, ] )

  except zmq.ZMQError as e:

            if ( e.errno in ( zmq.EINVAL,
                              zmq.EPROTONOSUPPORT,
                              zmq.ENOCOMPATPROTO,
                              )
                 ):
                 logger.error( "ZeroMQ TransportClass / Endpoint cannot be setup for [socketA]." )

            if ( e.errno in ( zmq.ETERM,
                              zmq.EMTHREAD,
                              )
                 ):
                 logger.error( "ZeroMQ Context is not ready to handle this request for [socketA]." )

            if ( e.errno in ( zmq.ENOTSOCK, ) ):
                 logger.error( "ZeroMQ operation was requested, but not on a valid [socketA]." )

       cleanUp( aContextINSTANCE, [ socketA, ] )

finally:
      # ...
      pass

def cleanUp( aContextToTERMINATE, aListOfSocketsToCLOSE = [] ):
    for      aSocket in aListOfSocketsToCLOSE:
        try:
             aSocket.close()             # external responsibility to setup LINGER as zero right at aSocket instantiation point
        except:
             pass
    try:
         aContextToTERMINATE.term()
    except:
         pass
    finally:
         # ...
         pass
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a specific reason you're setting linger to 0. I'm setting it to -1 before closing the sockets because I want the data to be available in the wire even if the sockets are closed after sending few messages.

Comment: Sure there is THE REASON. Any non-zero `LINGER` will block on an attempt to `.close()` and distributed-systems ought be so fair as not to block. Even when the program goes away, it ought behave blocking-free so as not to fall out of control -- in a blocking state your code has zero control of what happens & just passively hangs in the silence of external events ( that need not ever come ... ). Blocking resources and falling out of control is generally not a good idea, is it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what do you mean by "which sockets are alive". *Both* sockets must be closed regardless of which `connect`/`bind` call failed. In C libzmq terms, `zmq_close` is not the counterpart to `zmq_connect`/`zmq_bind`, but to `zmq_socket`. 
`zmq_socket` in pyzmq is already called by `Socket.__init__`.